# Copying data from excel to pdf form, works for the first but

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, acrobat

I want to export data from Excel to a pdf-Form using vba.
I used this approach:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/302309

When I copy just one field it works, but I want to copy all the fields from A1:K2 where the field titles are always in the top and the content in the rows below.
I think my problem is that I don't switch back to Excel when I am trying to copy the next value and field title. But I don't know how to do it properly.
So I would be really glad if someone could tell me.

The files could be downloaded here:
http://www.xn--frank-mller-zhb.net/Formulardings.zip

```
Sub Pdfdings()


Dim gApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
Dim avdoc As Acrobat.CAcroAVDoc
Dim gPDDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Const DOC_FOLDER As String = "C:\Users\Frank\Documents"
Dim x As Boolean

Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set gPDDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set avdoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

'Hides Acrobat - So Far So Good
'gApp.Hide

Dim FormApp As AFORMAUTLib.AFormApp
Dim AcroForm As AFORMAUTLib.Fields
Dim Field As AFORMAUTLib.Field
Dim z, i, j, n As Integer
Dim wksTab1 As Worksheet
Dim Feld, Inhalt As String

Set wksTab1 = Sheets("Tabelle2")

'Open PDF that I choose. Acrobat still has not flashed on my screen
j = 1
i = 2
While i < 3
    x = avdoc.Open(DOC_FOLDER & "\formular_ve01a.pdf", "temp")

    'Acrobat Now Pops up on my screen. However, I get an error without this line. avdoc.Show works the same as Maximize it seems.
    avdoc.Maximize (1)

    'Hides it again, right after it opens. This creates a flash
    'gApp.Hide

    Set FormApp = CreateObject("AFormAut.App")

    While j < 39



        'If the Maximize line is not there, this is where I receive error about document viewer
        Feld = wksTab1.Cells(1, j).Value
        Inhalt = wksTab1.Cells(i, j).Value

        For Each Field In FormApp.Fields
            If Field.Name = Feld Then
                Field.Value = Inhalt
            End If
        Next

        j = j + 1
        Wend
    Dim sDoc
    Set sDoc = avdoc.GetPDDoc
    saveOk = sDoc.Save(1, DOC_FOLDER & "\OK_Formular" & wksTab1.Cells(1, 1).Value & ".pdf")
    avdoc.Close (1)
    gApp.Exit
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution I got by the help of another forum

```
      <pre>While j < 39
         'If the Maximize line is not there, this is where I receive error about document viewer
         Feld = wksTab1.Cells(1, j).Value
         Inhalt = wksTab1.Cells(i, j).Value
         FormApp.Fields(Feld).Value = Inhalt
         j = j + 1
      Wend
```

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

1. Set A1:K2 as your print range
2. Set your printer to a PDF Writer (CutePDF or PDF995 or other)
3. Print

Comment: Hmm, it may work with CutePdf (but this would cost 30$), but PDF995 doesnt seem to do filling of pdf forms.
I want to fill an existing form and this way would work for the first field but it doesnt get the second field. Maybe due to focus issues. :(

Comment: Apologies.  I missed the part where you said that you were trying to fill in a pdf form.